Differential equation of a streamfunction
I am studying 2D incompressible potential flow, and there we are usually given the velocity potential $\varphi$.
From there, we then use the Cauchy–Riemann equations
$${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned} u={\frac {\partial \varphi }{\partial x}}&={\frac {\partial \psi }{\partial y}}\,,&v={\frac {\partial \varphi }{\partial y}}&=-{\frac {\partial \psi }{\partial x}}\,.\end{aligned}}}$$
and we obtain the stream function $\psi$ from which we can plot various streamlines.
I also heard that the equation of a streamline can also be viewed as
$${\displaystyle {\mathrm{d}x \over u}={\mathrm{d}y \over v}}. \tag1 \label{eq:1}$$
From there, we can also obtain the Cauchy–Riemann equations with
$$u \, \mathrm{d}y-v \, \mathrm{d}x=0$$
$$\mathrm{d}\psi = \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} \, \mathrm{d}x + \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y} \, \mathrm{d}y=0
$$
My question: What is the physical interpretation of the equation $\eqref{eq:1}$?
Is there a geometrical interpretation so that I can visualize it more intuitively?
Addendum
From the equation $\eqref{eq:1}$ we can obtain
$$u \, \mathrm{d}y-v \, \mathrm{d}x=0$$
but also
$$v \, \mathrm{d}x-u \, \mathrm{d}y=0.$$
But only the first equation seems to lead to the Cauchy–Riemann equations.
From the second one, we obtain:
$${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned} u={\frac {\partial \varphi }{\partial x}}&=-{\frac {\partial \psi }{\partial y}}\,,&v={\frac {\partial \varphi }{\partial y}}&={\frac {\partial \psi }{\partial x}}\,.\end{aligned}}}$$
How come they are equivalent?

You can interpret
$$\frac{dx}{u} = \frac{dy}{v}$$
as the condition that a streamline is everywhere tangent to velocity field. If you use a parameter $s$ to define the parametric equation of a streamline,
$$\mathbf{r}(s) = x(s) \hat{\mathbf{x}} + y(s) \hat{\mathbf{y}} \ ,$$
tangent vector in a point $P$, $\mathbf{r}_P = \mathbf{r}(s_P)$, is
$$\mathbf{t}(s_P) = \frac{d \mathbf{r}}{d s}(s_P) = \frac{d x}{ds}(s_P) \hat{\mathbf{x}} +\frac{d y}{ds}(s_P) \hat{\mathbf{y}} \ .$$
A streamline is defined to be that curve that is always tangent to the veloicty field, i.e. the tangent vector in a point of the streamline is proportional to the velocity field in the same point,
$$\frac{d \mathbf{r}}{ds}(s_P ) = \lambda(s_P) \mathbf{v}(\mathbf{r}_P) \ ,$$
being $\lambda(s_P)$ a proportionality constant, depending on the parametrization of the curve.
EDIT. Characteristic lines in fluid dynamics. Following one of your comment, I'm adding here a note about lines and kinematics in fluid dynamics. It's possible to define some families of lines, that coincide in steady flows:

Streamlines curves that are everywhere tangent to the vector field, for a given time $t$
Pathlines or trajectories: trajectory of a material particle, passing through a given point $P_0$ at a given time $t_0$
Streaklines geometric locus at a given time $t^*$ of all the material points passing through a given material point $P_0$, for time $t \in [t_0, t^*]$


And we can obtain $(1)$ by saying that $\frac{\frac{d x}{ds}(s_P)}{\frac{d y}{ds}(s_P)} = \frac{\lambda(s_P) u(x, y)}{\lambda(s_P) v(x, y)}$ and than $\frac{d x}{d y} = \frac{u(x, y)}{v(x, y)}$?

Can you please comment on the addendum on my question. What am I doing wrong when I get the wrong CR equations with opposite sign when choosing $v , \mathrm{d}x-u , \mathrm{d}y=0$ instead of $u , \mathrm{d}y-v , \mathrm{d}x=0$?

About the addendum: nothing wrong, you've just defined used two different definitions of the velocity field using two "streamfunctions", the classical one and its opposite as  $\mathbf{v} = \nabla \times \boldsymbol{\psi} = - \nabla \times \tilde{\boldsymbol{\psi}}$

About the first comment, you can "divide derivatives" (maybe don't do it in a Math class/exam if you are not 100% sure it's allowed) if you know what you're doing, i.e. a change of coordinates for 1-variable function, $x(s) = x(s(y))$, namely $\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{ds}{dy} \frac{dx}{ds}  = \frac{1}{\lambda , v} \lambda , u = \frac{u}{v}$.

I "divided" them because I didn't know another way of directly getting the equation $\frac{dx}{u}=\frac{dy}{v}$ and I wanted to obtain it from the definition $\frac{d \mathbf{r}}{ds}(s_P ) = \lambda(s_P) \mathbf{v}(\mathbf{r}_P) \ $ from where you left of.

Ah thanks, so I can just take it by fact that the streamfunction is something that is defined with ${\displaystyle d\psi =u,dy-v,dx}$ ?

A streamfunction that (upon some gauge condition) uniquely identify the velocity field can be defined for incompressible fields, since incompressibility constraint $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{v} = 0$ tells us that the velocity field can be written as the curl of a vector field, the streamfunction (or the vector potential), $\mathbf{v} = \nabla \times \boldsymbol{\psi}$. In 2D flows, you can take streamfunction with 1 component only, orthogonal w.r.t. the plane of motion. Try to verify that there's no mass flux across a streamline, and that streamlines have const value of $\psi(\mathbf{r}) = \psi^*$

I got it now. I think it can be best explained like this: Since the streamline is tangent to the vector field, it is colinear. Than  by definition of colinearity we have: $dr= a v$ where a is a scalar. and from that we obtain: $\frac{dx}{u} = \frac{dy}{v}$

If $\frac{dx}{u}=\frac{dy}{v}$ then both sides are equal to some $dt$, say, that is $$\frac{dx}{u}=\frac{dy}{v} = dt \tag{2},$$ which you can rearrange as
$$u(x,y)=\frac{dx}{dt}\\
v(x,y)=\frac{dy}{dt}.\tag{3}$$
This means that in the plane whose coordinates are $x,y$ there is a curve $x(t),y(t)$ whose tangents have coordinates $u(x,y),v(x,y).$

So than my equation $(1)$ is only valid for a stationary state?

i am not implying that; it is just easier to visualize geometrically if stationary, at least for me. you could have functions $u(x,y,t),v(x,y,t)$ in Eq (2) and (3).
